# Error al cargar entidad base en PHP con MVC+POO

Tags: php, mvc, poo, web

Estoy intentando ejecutar un sistema en PHP con MVC y POO, y me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in C:\Users\Javier\Desktop\Herramienta de Programacion\USBWebserver v8.6\root\sueldos\core\entidadbase.php on line 28
```

Mi codigo es (la linea del error es la que contiene el while)

```
    public function getAll(){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table ORDER BY id DESC");
        while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
            $resultSet[]=$row;
        }
        return $resultSet;
    }
```

Comment: En ningún momento le estas indicando que campo de tu tabla estas queriendo almacenar en el row, en esta parte de tu código ***$resultSet[]=$row;*** , debería quedar de la siguiente manera ***$resultSet[]=$row->CAMPO_MOSTRAR;***

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($query);` para ver lo que muestra. El error dice que `$query` no es un objeto. Puede que la consulta esté fallando.

Comment: @A.Cedano hize el var_dump($query) y me muestra que es bool(false)

Comment: Efectivamente, cuando `query` falla, devuelve `false`. Debes establecer un control de errores en tu código para controlar eso. Puede que lo que esté recibiendo en `$this->table` no sea un nombre de tabla válido, o que esa tabla no tenga una columna llamada `id`, o que `db` no sea una conexión válida. Hablamos de tres posibles errores que no son controlados en tu código. Si quieres saber el motivo exacto del error puedes hacer algo así, antes del `while`: **`if (!$query) { echo "Hubo un error: ".$this->db->error; } else {  //aquí la parte del while }` Prueba eso y dinos qué ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

La llamada a `query`  devuelve `false` cuando hay algún error. Es lo que está ocurriendo en tu caso, quizá porque lo que se recibe en `$this->table` no es un nombre de tabla válido, o porque esa tabla no tiene una columna llamada `id`.

Otro motivo por el que el código puede fallar es porque `$this->db` no sea una conexión válida. Deberías controlar todo eso en tu código. El control con respecto a la conexión debería hacerse quizá en otro ámbito del código.

Falta también un control adicional: la consulta podría traer cero filas, en cuyo caso convendría indicarlo de algún modo.

Asumiendo que haces un control de la conexión, el control relativo a este método podría quedar así:

```
public function getAll(){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table ORDER BY id DESC");
    #Control 1: ¿Hubo error en la consulta?
    if (!$query) {
        #Si hay error creamos una clave error en la respuesta
        #e imprimimos el error. 
        #OJO, usamos $this->db->error para depurar, luego lo cambias
        #no conviene mostrar mensajes de error internos en el código final
        $mData=array("error"=>$this->db->error);
    } else {
        #Control 2: ¿La consulta trae filas?
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $mData=array();
            while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                $mData[]=$row;
            }
        } else {
            #Si no trae filas, creamos una clave error en la respuesta
            $mData=array("error"=>"No se encontraron filas");
        }
    }

    return $mData;
}
```

### Modo de uso

En el contexto donde uses a `getAll` debes ser consciente de las modificaciones que se han hecho, para saber manejar la respuesta.

La lógica ha sido, que si ocurre algún error en la llamada, la respuesta tendrá una clave `error` dentro. Por tanto, en coherencia con esto, la respuesta debería ser manejada así:

```
$mResponse=$objeto->getAll();
if ( isset($mResponse["error"]) ) {
    echo $mResponse["error"];
} else {
    #No hubo error, leer o usar los datos que habrá en $mResponse
}
```